# Как получить значения из списка?

Tags: python, list, список

Есть список -

```
a = ['2020-06-11', '2020-06-12', '2020-06-13', '2020-06-14', '2020-06-15',
     '2020-06-16', '2020-06-17', '2020-06-18', '2020-06-19', '2020-06-20', 
     '2020-06-21', '2020-06-22', '2020-06-23']
```

И есть 2 переменные -

```
b = '2'
c = '3'
```

C начала списка надо удалить b элементов.
А с конца списка надо удалить с элементов.

Результат должен быть таким:

```
['2020-06-13', '2020-06-14', '2020-06-15', '2020-06-16', 
 '2020-06-17', '2020-06-18', '2020-06-19', '2020-06-20']
```

Comment: Почему у вас в заголовке "получить", а в вопросе "удалить"?

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Вот так вот для ненулевого `c`:

```
a = ['2020-06-11', '2020-06-12', '2020-06-13', '2020-06-14', '2020-06-15', '2020-06-16', '2020-06-17', '2020-06-18', '2020-06-19', '2020-06-20', '2020-06-21', '2020-06-22', '2020-06-23']
b = 2
c = 3

print(a[b:-c])
```

Если может быть нулём, то `print(a[b:-c or None])`

Answer (score 1):

```
result = a[int(b): -int(c)]
```

---

Объяснение:

Используем [срез](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/indeksy-i-srezy.html), в котором (после конверсии на целые числа) используем заданные числа (в форме строк — потому конверсия) как границы среза, вторую (верхнюю) как *отрицательное число*, чтобы позицию *считать с конца списка*, а не с начала.